# How to change the lightbox layout, so the image is float left and the description is float right?

Tags: jquery, lightbox2

I would like my lightbox popup to have the content in a wrapper container with the image on the left and the data (description) on the right. Is there an easy way to do this or has anyone had any success doing this?

Comment: Problem solved with a little fancy CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how others have accomplished this, but I found a way with some fancy CSS to accomplish my needs. Thanks for any who read my post if your interested in seeing how I accomplished my task let me know.

Comment: Glad you found a solution. It could be useful to post the way you solved this, for futur helps, while you are still remembering "how to" ;)